Where is CUDA deviceQuery installed in Pop!OS?
I am using Pop!OS and would like to run the CUDA deviceQuery tool, which can apparently provide info about the number of blocks and threads available for CUDA on an NVidia GPU. However, I am not sure where deviceQuery is installed on the system. Can anyone tell me where I can find the command, or which package I need to install to use it?

That is an example from Nvidia's CUDA programming guides. I don't think it'll be available as tool, unless you build it yourself. Love to be proven wrong on this, but the whole point of the existence of it is that you understand the source code, not that you can use it to get information on your hardware. there's other tools for that, which are actual tooling meant to be used by end-users; check nvidia-smi.
Building it from source is documented here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/blob/master/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/README.md

There is an example here of the command being called from an /opt/cuda/ directory; however, that folder doesn't exist on my system. I have used nvidia-smi, but haven't seen an option for it to state block/thread limits.

yes, again, if you followed the question linked in that question you linked to, you'd see that this is an example that came with the CUDASDK. not with the end-user cuda software.

Ok, so the deviceQuery command is available as a tool then - in the CUDA SDK. In that case, I think my question can be interpreted as: "how/can I install the CUDA SDK on Pop!OS?" (the linked guide seems to be for Ubuntu. I'm new to Pop!OS, but I know it is similar).

It's not a tool that is available; it's an example to compile, to show you how things are done in code. You might need to compile it from source. Which raises the question why you don't do what that tool does in your code yourself, seeing this information is relevant to people who optimize CUDA kernels (and similar shader problems) primarily.    the whole thing you need to call is cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev); and get the max threads-describing member from the struct whose address you pass in; hardly a problem if you're already writing CUDA software.

no, that's really not what I want to transport. What I want to say is: see, I understand you want to know this number, but it's really not something you need a separate tool for. Just copy the relevant source code, or build the example yourself – don't sink time into finding a binary tool that simply might not exist.

Ok, perhaps I misinterpreted what you were saying. I'm sorry and I have deleted my earlier comment. I see now what you meant. I am actually developing a CUDA kernel in Julia - I asked some of the Julia CUDA folks and it seems their CUDA.jl package gives access to this functionality for querying the CUDA device attributes. Thanks for your help and sorry again for being bad-tempered.

@Time4Tea don't worry! I myself could have phrased things nicer, and I'm happy you're exploring things!
